# How to decide to have a foreign key or not

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys, database-normalization

I have a parent table which contains `demographics` and `consent` data.

The parent table looks like as below

```
Person_id, Age, gender, Name,   DOB,     Consent_agreed, Agreed_share_phone_number, agreed_share_email  
   1       21     M      FM , 10/1/90       N                     N                     N
   2       23     F      MF , 11/1/92       Y                     Y                     Y
```

I am planning to store the data like below

```
DEMO Table

Person_id,    Age,     gender,     Name,       DOB    
     111       21       M           FM ,     10/1/90       
     222       23       F           MF ,     11/1/92  

CONSENT Table

Consent_Id    Person_id    Consent_agreed    Phone_number         email
    1             111             N              N                 N
    2             222             Y              Y                 Y
```

I have created a seperate table for consent because a person may update his consent over time and there might be multiple records.

Am I right to normalize it this way?

How should I decide whether to provide the `consent_id` in the `DEMO table` or not.

Should the DEMO table columns be like as below, with `consent_id` indicating the latest consent status or consent status should not be included in demo table

```
Person_id,    Age,     gender,     Name,       DOB, consent_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"a person may update his consent over time and there might be multiple records." Multiple consent rows for a person is definetly a reason to split the tables the way you've done it.

If an effective consent is always the latest row in `consent` for a person  (`demographics` row) there is no reason to store `consent_id` in `demographics`.

Comment: thanks, upvoted. So, you mean to say that if I can find the latest consent status of a person by (querying) and finding is latest row (last row) which will give his recent consent status, you say we dont have to store them in `demo` table. Did I understand that right?

Comment: @TheGreat, yes exactly.

Answer (score 2):

The answers provided above are absolutely correct. But If I am the developer, I will question as follows:

1. As you mentioned, there might be number of consents over time, where is the timestamp column which records it? I advice you to add that column.
2. Do you have to always show the latest consent status? If yes, your idea of having latest consent status in person table is good. If not, I advice you to have a view which joins both person and consent and show the latest consent, whenever required. In this way, you will save less data, which means no redundancy of consent status.

Hope I had given you a proper answer.

Regards,
Chaitanya

Answer (score 1):

I think;

The demo table has been designed correctly, you should not edit again. But the design of consent table, which related with your usage, may be changed. If you want to see all consent data, all data can be inside a table. Unless you want to see all consent data, you can saved the latest data in the consent table. And old consent data may be saved in a consent history table. In this way, you can access more fastly to the latest data.